# How to get and parse a serialized string using protobuf in java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, apache-flink

There is a client which serialize some values using protobuf. This client is programmed by python. I send the serialization result to a java code using socket:

```
serializedRow = t_event.SerializeToString()
sock.send(serializedRow)
```

In java code the message is received as string, but at the step of "ParseFrom" function, there is some ambiguous Errors. As the argument of ParseFrom is Bytes, before passing the string, it is converted to Bytes.

```
byte[] bytes = row.getBytes();
TaxiEvent taxiEvent1 = TaxiEvent.ParseFrom(bytes);
int sec = taxiEvent1.getTripTimeInSecs();
```

The java code is running in context of Apache Flink, as a result the Error message is very long and not clear. but when I omit the parsefrom line, no error occurs and obviously by omitting this line the received data couldn't be used.

The version of protobuf is 3.5.0.

Comment: maybe a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help...or just try to create a program as simple as possible to just do the serialization and parsing...

Comment: if you are using the binary encoding (as opposed to the java encoding), you're probably corrupted the data by treating it as text; it is a very common error

Comment: @MarcGravell Maybe...
what's the solution?

Comment: @komeilsh the first thing to do is to check the bytes in `serializedRow` vs `bytes`. If you can't get the same data at both ends: nothing else will work

Answer (score -1):

A solution is to serialize/deserialize in `JSON` using `Json.Printer` and `Json.Parser` classes provided by `protobuf-java-util`.

#### Java implementation

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</parent>
```

Example of code:

```
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;

public class EventHelper {

    private static final JsonFormat.Printer PRINTER = JsonFormat.printer();
    private static final JsonFormat.Parser PARSER = JsonFormat.parser();

    public static String toFunctionId(Event event) throwsInvalidProtocolBufferException {
        return PRINTER.print(event);
    }

    public static Event toEvent(String functionId) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
        Event.Builder builder = Event.newBuilder();
        PARSER.merge(functionId, builder);
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```